# How to let sudoedit source ~/.bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, vim

I have Vim shortcuts which requires me to edit the `~/.bashrc` file to stop some terminal shortcuts like `<C-S>` - which freezes the whole terminal - so I can use them in Vim. when I open a Vim file like `vim somefile` this works perfectly. However, when trying to edit system files using `sudoedit somefile` my shortcuts which require the terminal to stop using them while Vim is running are not working and `<C-s>` still freezes the whole terminal. I tried adding the same function in `~/.bashrc` to `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/bash_profile` but non of them work. is there a way I can do that? I know I can use `sudo vim somefile` but this is doesn't load my `~/.vimrc` file so I will lose all my settins.

Here is the function in my `~/.bashrc` file if that of any help:

```
#  No ttyctl, so we need to save and then restore terminal settings
vim()
{
   local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save)"
   stty stop '' -ixoff
   command vim "$@"
   stty "$STTYOPTS"
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay!!

I found the answer myself if anyone is interested.
It was just so stupid of me. My function calls `command vim "$@"` which means it's not used when `sudoedit` is called. 
So all I had to do is add a second function with the same content but named `sudovim` and it calles 'sudoedit' instead of vim. so now when I want to edit with `sudoedit` I just `sudovim filename` and when I want to edit without `sudoedit` I just call `vim filename`
Here is my first function:

```
# stop some terminal shortcuts while using vim
vim()
{
   local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save)"
   stty stop '' -ixoff
   command vim "$@"
   stty "$STTYOPTS"
}
```

and the one with `sudoedit`:

```
# same as above but calls sudoedit which is defined in $SUDO_EDITOR
# use sudovim to write in sudoedit
sudovim()
{
    local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save)"
    stty stop '' -ixoff
    command sudoedit "$@"
    stty "$STTYOPTS"
}
```

put this in your `~/.bashrc` then map  in `~/.vimrc`